# Does there exist a countably infinite extension ring of the rational numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory

This question came up as I was thinking about whether there could be a ring with the conventional addition and multiplication defined on it that contains all of $\mathbb{Q}$ and at least one other element and is countable. Intuitively, a set that is related to $\mathbb{Q}$ in the same way $\mathbb{Q}$ is related to $\mathbb{Z}$. I tried to attack the question using the fact that if a ring $B$ contains all of $A$ and at least one other element $c$, it must contain every element of the form $a_0 +a_1c +...  +a_nc^n$. i.e. every element of the polynomial ring $A[c]$. But unfortunately couldn't get anywhere that way. There is some related stuff on the internet. Notably, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427280/does-a-countably-infinite-power-set-exist) and [this](https://www.quora.com/Is-every-countably-infinite-field-isomorphic-to-the-rationals) (the second one seems to be evidence *for* the existence of such a set). The first link, however, refers to power sets which are different to 'polynomial sets' at least in the fact that a 'polynomial set' doesn't contain infinite polynomials (sequences of coefficients). Cantor's diagonal argument can't be applied for the same reason.

Comment: Well, what about $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ ? That is to say, the set of numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt 2$ where $a,b\in \mathbb Q$.  Usual rules of arithmetic.

Comment: Should say, that's an example of an [Algebraic Number Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field) and there are many examples of such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $\Bbb Q[x]$, the ring of polynomials. If you want to have something "nicer", look at $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$, or perhaps $\Bbb Q^{\text{alg}}$, the field of all algebraic numbers (which is a countable subfield of $\Bbb C$), or its intersection with $\Bbb R$.

All of these are countable. $\Bbb Q[x]$ is countable because the set of finite sequences from a countable set is itself countable, and $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ can be either seen as a quotient of $\Bbb Q[x]$ (so it is countable as the image of a countable set), or directly as $\{p+q\sqrt 2\mid p,q\in\Bbb Q\}\cong\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$. And finally, $\Bbb Q^{\text{alg}}$ is countable because each number is the root of a polynomial in $\Bbb Q$, and each polynomial has finitely many roots, so it is a countable union of finite sets, and therefore countable.

Similarly, you can consider $\Bbb Q(\pi)$, or even just adjoin any new symbol with some equation, $\langle\Bbb Q,x\mid x+x=0, x\neq 0\rangle$, so we add an element of additive order $2$, and the ring is no longer a field.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}^{\text{alg}}$ is not a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ so it cannot be a quotient ring of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: @MorA.: I'm not familiar with a theorem like that.

Comment: Okay, now it should work. (I tried being lazy.)